# Is there a better way to sanitize input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, xpages, sanitization

I wanted to write a javascript function to sanitize user input and remove any unwanted and dangerous characters.

It must allow only the following characters:

- Alfanumeric characters (case insentitive): [a-z][0-9].
- Inner whitespace, like "word1 word2".
- Spanish characters (case insentitive): [áéíóúñü].
- Underscore and hyphen [_-].
- Dot and comma [.,].
- Finally, the string must be trimmed with trim().

My first attempt was:

```
function sanitizeString(str){
str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9áéíóúñü_-\s\.,]/gim,"");
return str.trim();
}
```

But if I did:

```
sanitizeString("word1\nword2")
```

it returns:

```
"word1
word2"
```

So I had to rewrite the function to remove explícitly \t\n\f\r\v\0:

```
function sanitizeString(str){
str = str.replace(/([^a-z0-9áéíóúñü_-\s\.,]|[\t\n\f\r\v\0])/gim,"");
return str.trim();
}
```

I'd like to know:

1. Is there a better way to sanitize input with javascript?
2. Why \n and \t doesn't matches in the first version RegExp?

Comment: Save yourself some time and don't bother, do it on the server. Javascript filtering is too easy to bypass

Comment: Actually I'm doing that on the server with SSJS because I'm using XPages on the backend. I could say the same if I was using Node.js. :)

Comment: You're allowing new line, tab etc. with `\s`. If you just want to allow spaces, use a space in the regular expression instead.

Comment: `\s` doesn't mean "a space". It includes "tab", "space", "carriage return", "new line", "vertical tab", and "form feed".

Comment: @RobG Add it as an answer, \s was the problem. You mentioned that before Derek (also I had to move the hyphen at the end).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The new version of the **sanitizeString** function:

```
function sanitizeString(str){
    str = str.replace(/[^a-z0-9áéíóúñü \.,_-]/gim,"");
    return str.trim();
}
```

The main problem was mentioned by @RobG and @Derek: (@RobG write your comment as an answer and I will accept it) \s doesn't mean what now [w3Schools says](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp)

> Find a whitespace character

It means what [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

> Matches a single white space character, including space, tab, form
>   feed, line feed. Equivalent to [
>   \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​\u2001\u2002​\u2003\u2004​\u2005\u2006​\u2007\u2008​\u2009\u200a​\u2028\u2029​​\u202f\u205f​\u3000].

I trusted in w3Schools when I wrote the function.

A second change was to move the dash character (-) to the end in order to avoid it's range separator meaning.

- Note 1: This is a server side validation using javascript.
- Note 2:
  (for IBM Notes XPagers) I love javascript in XPages SSJS. This is
  simpler for me than the Java way.