# Remove script tags from serialized XML without executing scripts, in browser?

Tags: javascript, html

I am running some code in NodeJS to remove script tags before executing the scripts. Is there a simple way to do something similar in a browser environment?

```
import cheerio from "cheerio";

export async function removeScripts(serializedSvg: string): Promise<string> {
  const $ = cheerio.load(serializedSvg, {
    xmlMode: true,
    decodeEntities: false,
  });

  Array.from($("script")).forEach((el: CheerioElement) => {
    $(el).remove();
  });

  return $.xml();
}
```

Comment: afaik, cheerio is basically core jQuery for node. So just look up how to parse xml with jQuery and parts of your code can be used 1:1.

Comment: @ChrisG: Thank you, that's a good idea

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a better way to sanitize input with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187013/is-there-a-better-way-to-sanitize-input-with-javascript)